# Why does a cast from int to float round the value?

Tags: c, casting, int, rounding

I'm reading CS:APP, and regarding casts it says that when casting **from int to float, the number cannot overflow, but it may be rounded.**

It seemed odd to me as I didn't know what there was to round, so I've tried it out. I thought that this would only be the case for very large integers (near `INT_MAX`/`INT_MIN`), but rounding happens at values around a hundred million as well. (Not sure where exactly this happens first).

Why does this happen? The range of `float` far exceeds that of `int`. One might say that floating point numbers cannot be represented exactly, but when converting from `int`to `double` there is no change in value. The advantage of `double`over `float` is that it has greater range and precision. But `float`still has enough range to "encapsulate" integers, and precision shouldn't really matter as integers have no decimal places (well, all 0), or am I thinking wrong?

Here's some output that I got (here is the code: http://pastebin.com/K3E3A6Ni):

```
FLT_MAX = 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000  
INT_MAX     = 2147483647  
(float)INT_MAX = 2147483648.000000  
(double)INT_MAX = 2147483647.000000  
INT_MIN     = -2147483648  
(float)INT_MIN = -2147483648.000000  

====other values close to INT_MIN INT_MAX====  
INT_MAX-1     = 2147483646  
(float)INT_MAX-1 = 2147483648.000000  
INT_MIN+1     = -2147483647  
(float)INT_MIN+1 = -2147483648.000000  
INT_MAX-2      = 2147483645  
(float)INT_MAX-2  = 2147483648.000000  
INT_MAX-10     = 2147483637  
(float)INT_MAX-10 = 2147483648.000000  
INT_MAX-100         = 2147483547  
(float)INT_MAX-100  = 2147483520.000000  
INT_MAX-1000         = 2147482647  
(float)INT_MAX-1000 = 2147482624.000000  

(float)1.234.567.809 = 1234567808.000000  
(float)1.234.567.800 = 1234567808.000000  
(float)1.000.000.005 = 1000000000.000000  
(float)800.000.003   = 800000000.000000  
(float)500.000.007   = 500000000.000000  
(float)100.000.009   = 100000008.000000
```

Comment: Fun fact: `2147483647.0f == 2147483648.0f`

Comment: @dmg Does not the fun fact depend on rounding mode?

Comment: Floating point numbers prove the existence of God by negation because they are clearly the work of Satan.  :-)

Comment: @Bob Jarvis Satire aside, [The Father of Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kahan) and others made a robust, effective long term FP design.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming that by `float` you mean a 32-bit IEEE-754 binary floating point value, by `double` you mean a 64-bit IEEE-754 binary floating point value, and by `int` you mean a 32-bit integer.

> Why does this happen? The range of float far exceeds that of int

Yes, but the *precision* of `float` is only 7-9 decimal digits. To be more specific, the significand is only 24 bits wide... so if you're trying to store 32 bits of information in there, you're going to have problems.

> but when converting from `int` to `double` there is no change in value

Sure, because a `double` has a 53-bit significand - plenty of room for a 32-bit integer there!

To think of it another way, the gap between consecutive `int` values is always 1... whereas the gap between consecutive `float` values starts very, very small... but increases as the magnitude of the value increases. It gets to "more than 2" well before you hit the limit of `int`... so you get to the stage where not every `int` can be exactly represented.

To think of it *another* way, you can simply use the [pigeon-hole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)... even ignoring NaN values, there can be *at most* 2<sup>32</sup> `float` values, and at least one of those is not the exact value of an `int` - take 0.5, for example. There are 2<sup>32</sup> `int` values, therefore at least one `int` value doesn't have an exact `float` representation.

Comment: didn't knew about the pigeon-hole principle, but this is how I explained to myself in laymen terms why not all integers can be represented by floats.

Comment: I always thought that precision refers to the number of decimal places. For instance, float may have 6 while double may have 15. So what exactly does precision of 7-9 decimal digits mean?

Comment: @Beko: It means that the precision of a *binary* floating point value is somewhat hard to specify - particularly when normalization comes into play. Basically, if you're *relying* on more than 7 with `float`, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 7):

A typical `float` that is implemented with the 32-bit IEEE-754 representation has only 24 bits for the significand, which allows for about 7 decimal digits of precision. So you'll see rounding as soon as you hit the millions (2<sup>24</sup> ≈ 16M).

(For a `double`, the significand has 53 bits, and 2<sup>53</sup> ≈ 9×10<sup>15</sup>.)